# Convergence of exponential of monotonic function?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function, monotone-functions

Let $f:{\mathbb R}_+\rightarrow{\mathbb R}_+$ be an increasing continuous function. We now that
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{f(x)}{r}\right)^{r} =e^{f(x)}.$$
Then
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}\left\vert 1- \frac{e^{f(x)}}{\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{r}\right)^{r}}\right\vert = 0.$$
My question is (a hint would suffice), is this convergence monotone? This is, does the sequence, for each $x>0$, $G_r = \left\vert 1- \frac{e^{f(x)}}{\left(1+\frac{f(x)}{r}\right)^{r}}\right\vert \downarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow\infty$ (**monotonically**)?

Comment: Did you want to take the absolute value? This makes each $G_r$ positive and surely answers your question.

Comment: @hexomino It converges to zero, yes, but the monotonicity is not immediate to me, which is what I am more interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing: I'm wondering whether you mean **uniform** convergence, because if you are occupied merely with **monotonic** convergence, then $f(x)$ has little significance, and one can replace it with any $c>0$.

The question boils down to the behaviour of $(1+\frac{c}{r})^r$.

Recall that $(1+\frac{1}{r})^r$ monotonically increases. Now replace $r$ with $\frac{r}{c}$. Then $(1+\frac{c}{r})^{\frac{r}{c}}$ monotonically increases too. Note that $c$ is a constant.

Comment: You are right, $f$ is irrelevant in this case. So, am I correct to conclude that $(1+\frac{c}{r})^r$ converges monotonically to $e^c$?

Comment: Exactly. If you are interested, the fastest way of proving the monotonicity of $(1+\frac{1}{r})^r $ involves the AM-GM inequality.